# Why is this file_get_contents() sometimes working and sometimes not?

Tags: php, api, youtube, file-get-contents

I am building a small interface to show livestreamed video from a YouTube channel to a webpage. I got the API key, I set it up and it worked. But then I couldn't access certain information from the json I got back from the YouTube server.

I tried a few things, fixing whatever breaks on the go, but I realised that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't... I searched other threads but I can't understand anymore what's happening.

So the questions are:

1. How to use file_get_contents_url() to get info about a Youtube channel every time without HTTP response failure?
2. Why is my testing using all the units I have as a quota from Google's API? (It runs out of units in a 50 refreshes or so)

My code

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

# Enable Error Reporting and Display:
error_reporting(~0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$API_KEY = 'API KEY HERE';
$ChannelID = ' CHANNEL ID HERE';

$channelInfo = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId='.$ChannelID.'&type=video&eventType=live&key='.$API_KEY;

$extractInfo = file_get_contents_url($channelInfo);
$extractInfo = str_replace('},]',"}]",$extractInfo);
$showInfo = json_decode($extractInfo, true);

if($showInfo['pageInfo']['totalResults'] === 0){
    echo 'Users channel is Offline';
}else{
    echo 'Users channel is LIVE!';
}

$videoId = $extractInfo['items'][0]['id']["videoId"];

if ($videoId = 0) {
    echo "<h2>No live stream yet.</h2>";
} else {
    echo "</h2>$videoId</h2>";
}
?>
```

What I need is:

1. to access my YouTube channel,
2. get the content as json,
3. turn it into a php array,
4. where I get the *videoId* of the livestreamed video
5. and display it.

When I echo `$extractInfo` I get

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse", 
    "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/yOWNawoTMP4atq-Ylgqt-1puBAQ\"", 
    "regionCode": "NL", 
    "pageInfo": { 
            "totalResults": 0, 
            "resultsPerPage": 5 
            }, 
    "items": [] 
} 0
```

Comment: Can you show what you get back in `$channelInfo` please

Comment: Why are you using str_replace on a json string? In my opinion that could be the reason you get problems. If you str_replace and destroy the format of the json, then json_decode will return false/null

Comment: @Andreas That was why I asked to see `$channelInfo` to see if the OP was shooting themselves in the foot or if there was a reason for that fudge code

Comment: @RiggsFolly `$channelInfo` is just the "link". `$extractInfo` is probably what you wanted to ask for :-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly when I echo `$channelInfo` I get whatever @Andreas said. Just the link. When I echo `$extractInfo` I get  `{"kind": "youtube#searchListResponse", "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/yOWNawoTMP4atq-Ylgqt-1puBAQ\"", "regionCode": "NL", "pageInfo": { "totalResults": 0, "resultsPerPage": 5 }, "items": [] } `

Comment: @RiggsFolly I must admit I got this code from somewhere so didn't really think about the str_replace(). I am very eager to learn, so please share what's bad practice or illogical faff code :)

Comment: Did you do that BEFORE doing the `str_replace()` or AFTER?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did that (if you refer to echoing the `$extractInfo`) BEFORE and AFTER and there seems to be no difference.

Btw, now I am getting a failed HTTP request on `file_get_contents()` line and I suspect it's because I ran out of these quota units again.

Comment: THen it does not look like the `str_replace()` is requried. But it will not actually do anything anyway so it is not the cause of your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the response you are showing us is complete, then if you get a channel that is offline then the items array is sent but is empty, so your code needs to check for that
possibility

```
// only run this if we actually have an array to process
if ( count($showInfo['items']) > 0 ) {
    $videoId = $showInfo['items'][0]['id']["videoId"];

    if ($videoId = 0) {
        echo "<h2>No live stream yet.</h2>";
    } else {
        echo "</h2>$videoId</h2>";
    }
} else {
    echo "No items in the array";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I refactored the code so now it is like this:

`if ( count($showInfo['items']) > 0 ) {
    $videoId = $showInfo['items'][0]['id']["videoId"];

    if($showInfo['pageInfo']['totalResults'] === 0){
    echo 'Users channel is Offline';

    }
    else{
    echo 'Users channel is LIVE!';
    echo "<br>Your video ID is $videoId";
    }

} else {
    echo "No items in the array";
}`

However, my web browser doesn't detect when I stop the livestream. It still shows that it is running. What could that be?

Comment: Yea, that makes more sense

Comment: thanks again, I need to figure out why it doesn't detect when the livestream has ended. How fast should this happen or is it up to the API and Google's servers?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help with that part

Comment: Alright, thanks for everything else! Should I post the question in another thread to ask specifically or should I just wait for response here?